# Telegram SetWebHook Self Signed Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, telegram, telegram-bot, asp.net-webhooks

I'm Trying to Send a Self Signed Certificate To telegram .
The Configuration will be done through [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) And My Bot Server is Ok (tests through `getUpdates` and action call over ssl connection responded successfully).

Here is what i send to telegram :

```
api.telegram.org/botMY TOKEN/setWebhook?url=MY SWERVER IP:443/api/webhook
```

and i **DO** attach the PUBLICKEY.pem as a binary body to the request.

Here is what i get :

`{   "ok": true,   "result": true,   "description": "Webhook was set" }`

the problem is when i check the webHook via `getWebHookInfo` :

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "94.183.157.125:443/api/webhook",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 5,
    "last_error_date": 1476206652,
    "last_error_message": "Connection timed out"
  }
}
```

in which the attribute `"has_custom_certificate" : false` means it did't get my certificate :\

What am i doing wrong here ?

Any alternatives to [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) ??

**One Step Further**

I tried the `HttpClient` as below but it didn't work eighter :\

```
public string SetWebHook()
    {
        FileStream paramFileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\PATH.......\YOURPUBLIC.pem", FileMode.Open);
        HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);
        var response = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "Certificate", "YOURPUBLIC.pem");
             response = client.PostAsync("https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/setWebhook?url=MYSERVERIP:443/api/webhook", formData).Result.ToString();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: It feels like no one has ever tried to run self certificated telegram webHook on ASP :D

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Nope! I'm kind of hopeless...but haven't tried curl yet

Answer (score 0):

You must use curl to upload your certificate (pem)

And

You should use HTTPS:// for your url

Comment: and another important point:

- the domain name in the certificate should match your actual domain name